# Power Query Web.Contents fails due to unsupported browser

Tags: excel, powerquery

I was using power query to pull in the nfl schedule from the espn website. It has been working pretty good (although slow to refresh) until this week. I started getting no data returned. The error said I was using an unsupported browser.

The query was :

```
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/6/year/2022/seasontype/2"))
```

I have been searching and have not found a means to change the user agent. I investigated and found the user agent used is :

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Zoom 3.6.0)
```

From my research on whatismybrowser.com this appears to be : Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8 Internet Explorer 7 Compatibility View

My computer is running Windows 11 64 bit with Chrome (105.0.xxx) as the default browser and MS Edge (106.0.xxx) also installed.

Is there a way to change what user agent powerquery uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried passing in a custom user agent in the header?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents

```
headers = [#"User-Agent" = "Your agent here"],
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/6/year/2022/seasontype/2", [Headers = headers]))
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked and I now have data again.